# MS Teams - TaskModule close the window

Tags: html, botframework, microsoft-teams

I display a third party web page(client page) in the task module

1. using Deeplink 
   https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/botid?url=https:test.com/test.html&height=450&width=510&title=Custom+Form&completionBotId=botid
2. new AdaptiveOpenUrlAction() { Title = "Enable MS Team access", Url = new Uri(DeeplinkHelper.DeepLink }

Here the web page is opening in Task module, I need to close this task module by clicking the button available on the web page(URL) and send the result to completionBotId.

Any sample pls that need to implement in client-side code.

Comment: When you want to close the Task module this should be handled in sumitHandler() method. You can directly submit the page data and return true to close the task module or you can pass any action on submit to close in submitHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps to make this work:

1. you need to reference the [Teams Javascript SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msteams-client?view=msteams-client-js-latest) in your web page
2. When your user clicks the button, you would call `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask`  in your 'click' event handler. There are a few parameter options for this method, depending on whether you want it to send anything back to your bot. To simply close the window, call `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(null);`, or if you want to send an object back, call `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(whateverObjectYouWantToSendBack);`